# Can I build SSO without access protocol (such as: kerberos, ldap)

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, system, protocols, kerberos

I want to build a SSO system for web applications, but I dont want to use any protocol, just a plain cookie and session. can I?

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no.

The concept of SSO *requires* that a client either:

- possess a verifiable identity / authorisation assertion (credential) that it can transmit to multiple *relying parties*, or
- negotiate with a relying party for the relying party to receive a verifiable assertion "just in time" (i.e. during login), or
- some combination of the above.

Since cookies are scoped to a single domain, you cannot build an SSO system with just cookies and browser sessions.

If you don't wish to use Kerberos there are various other SSO protocols.